# Can spin be infinite?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, particle-physics

Can [spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)) of a particle or a group of particles become infinity? Explain plz. Is there any representation for spins like dot(for $S=0$) and arrow (for $S=1$)? If so what for $S= \infty$?

Comment: please don't use capslock (I changed the question title)

Comment: ok.thanx for changing the name.sorry 4 my mistake.!!

Answer (score 3):

Compact group $SU(2)$ really has only finite-dimensional unitary irreducible representations, but
formally it is not enough to close the question, because there are unitary irreducible infinite-dimensional representations of spin group $SL(2,C)$ of four-dimensional relativistic Lorentz group and they were used in some models, below is a cite from: N.N. Bogolubov, A. A. Logunov, A.I. Oksak, I. Todorov, General principles of quantum field theory, Springer, 1989. Appendix I for chapter 9

> The concept of an infinite-component
>   field (ICF for short) is the result of
>   abandoning the "technical" requirement
>   that the representations of the
>   Lorentz group according to which the
>   fields transform (say, in the Wightman
>   formalism) be finite-dimensional. This
>   idea turned up at the earliest stages
>   of quantum field theory: in 1932,
>   Majorana gave an example of an
>   infinite-dimensional wave equation 
>   $(i \Gamma^\mu \partial_\mu – M) \psi(x) = 0$ 
>   without negative-energy solutions
>   of non-negative square mass, that is,
>   without "antiparticles".

…

> Running ahead (see
>   §1.3), it should be noted, however,
>   that the description of composite
>   systems by means of ICF's has met with
>   difficulties which, it would seem,
>   require a weakening of the postulate
>   of (strict) locality.

Comment: Dear @Alex 'qubeat'. Sorry for this nitpicking comment, but the statement that _the compact group $SU(2)$ has only finite-dimensional irreducible representations_ is not correct. There are non-unitary infinite-dimensional irreducible representations of the Lie group $SU(2)$. Of course, in physics one usually requires unitarity.

Comment: @Qmechanic: why does the unitarian trick fail on these irreducible representations?

Comment: Sorry, of course I missed word "unitary"

Comment: Theorem about representation of compact groups mentioned above may be found, e.g. in:  A. O. Barut, R. Raczka, Theory of Group Representations
and Applications, (PWN, Warszawa, 1977).

Comment: The representations are massless, so maybe it is better to say that they have infinite helicity?!?

Comment: No, the mass is $M$.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Anyway, I would like to see an example of representation you are talking about.

Comment: @Qmechanic: I believe your statement is not correct. By usual Weylish arguments one can always unitarize a representation of the compact group (just impose arbitrary Hilbert structure and then define new scalar product by averaging over the group action). By Peter-Weyl theorem then every such representation decomposes into sum of unitary irreducibles. What you had in mind was probably the rep. theory of $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ which indeed admits non-unitary reps. But this is precisely because the group is not compact.

Comment: @wnoise and @Marek. The standard Weyl unitarian trick for compact groups $G$ and representations $\rho:G\to B(H)$ into bounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$, only preserves the strong operator topology. Thus if the representation is continuous in, e.g., the weak operator topology, the averaging procedure may destroy this notion of continuity.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any theory involving a notion of infinite spin. Generally, spin is a quantum number that takes (typically) small integer or half integer values. In principle, you can have a system with as high a spin as you would like, but that's not infinite. So I'd say the answer is no.

Comment: There *is* an exotic phenomenon in in general relativity regarding large "spin"/angular momentum. It does not have much to do with your question, so I'll add it as a comment:
A massive rotating body will drag space along around itself. This "frame-dragging" has been measured for the earth, but it is a very small effect. However, around a quickly rotating black hole it can get so strong that something in orbit would have to move with light speed against it, just to stay where it is (relative to the surrounding ~flat space)! With a lot of handwaving, one could speak of an infinity here :-)

Comment: the angular momentum of such a rotating black hole is perfectly finite, though--with a maxiumum magnitude proportional to $M^{2}$

Comment: @Jerry: Thanks for adding the clarification. I was not claiming that the angular momentum was infinite :-), it was more of an interesting anecdote (hence a comment and not an answer).

Comment: But intrinsic angular momentum,L=nh/(2pi),which is equal to spin.So when n becomes infinity,L is also infinity.So my question is ,is there any physical significance for this statement rather than a theoretical statement?

Answer (score 0):

The three-dimensional spin group is the compact group $SU(2)$, which has only finite-dimensional representations. Hence, the spin is always a non-negative integer or half-integer.

Comment: Dear @Oluf. The answer (v1) contains a wrong statement. There exist infinite-dimensional unitary representations of the compact group $SU(2)$. Take, e.g., infinitely many copies of the trivial or adjoint representation.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Sorry, I meant to say _irreducible_ representation. And of course it is not obvious that a particle has to transform in a irreducible representation, so I guess my answer is a bit too naive. By the way, doesn't infinitely many copies of the trivial representation still just contain a single state?

Comment: @Oluf. In usually terminology, the trivial (=singlet) group representation is $1$-dim, and the adjoint (=triplet) group representation is $3$-dim. Hope this answers your comment.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Sure. I'm just saying that a tensor product of even an infinite number of singlets still is a singlet. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Oluf. No, you're right, the tensor product of two singlet representations is again a singlet representation. In my comment above, I was alluding to direct sums (as opposed to tensor products) of singlet representations.

Answer (score 0):

A paper elaborating on Majorana's ideas is https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05965. In this paper the author expands the original ideas of Ettore Majorana about infinite dimensional representations of the Lorentz group, which could represent particles with arbitrary spin. This is just theoretical, no such particle has ever been observed so far. In this article it is described a theory of a peculiar quantum particle with a mass-spin relation given by $$m_{J_n} = \frac{m_0}{J_n + 1/2}$$ where $m_0$ is the rest mass of the particle, and $J_n = s + n$ is the total angular momentum, $s$ the "ground state spin" and $n$ is a quantum number.
A generic state can be expressed as the linear combination of infinite "spin-mass states":
$$ |\phi \rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n |J_n \rangle . $$ In this theory, the amplitude of excited state is a function of the particle speed:
$$
c_n = \sqrt{\left( \frac{v}{c} \right)^n - \left( \frac{v}{c} \right)^{n+1}}
$$
This system has no experimental relevance, but, for what I know, it is the more complete theory about the "infinite spin" possibility.

Comment: Nicola your text does not constitute a valid answer to the provided question. The linked paper may provide an answer but you should at least provide a brief explanation of the paper's content in order to explain the solution provided there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I tried to re-edit the answer, if still it does not fit, I can just delete it.

Comment: Can't really say if this is Indeed an answer 'cause this is not my field. I just tried to point out that you should provide an adequate answer so that people who see it in the future can understand how the problem stated in the question is solved.